# Isn't a “gonner” or “gonna” slang for a person about to die?

Tags: pronunciation, slang, contractions

(I think this "blank" moment of mine is what is called in AmEng a *brain fart*, so be it)

Isn't ‘a gonner/gonna’ slang for a person who is about to die? It's said in situations where, potentially, someone risks getting themselves killed. Maybe children also use it when play acting. I'm sure there must be something similar but the dictionary entries tell me that ‘[gonna](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gonna)’ is a contraction of "going to" and ‘[gonner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gonner)’ is not listed in The Free Dictionary.

For example:

> If you do that (a dangerous thing) you're a gonner

I presume *a gonna* or *a gonner* (or something similar) is short for “a person who is *going to* die”.

Comment: to add to NVZ's answer, I've never heard goner pronounced as ˈɡônə,ˈɡənə (gonna) in New York, California, DC or on TV.

Comment: It's however you pronounce "gone" plus "er." No more and no less.

Comment: If you heard the expression "He's a goner," spoken by someone with the affectations common to the Northeastern US, it would sound like: "He's a 'gawnuh'". The difference would be: "He's 'gunna' (gonna) die."

Comment: In my experience "goner" refers to some person or thing that has (or will very soon) ceased to function.  Very often used in a figurative or hyperbolic sense.  Not necessarily a person, and not implying death -- an employee may be a "goner" if he's targeted for a layoff, eg, and one might refer to a badly damaged bike tire as a "goner", since it can't be repaired.  I've never heard "gonna", the contraction of "going to", used in this sense, though certainly someone might mispronounce "goner" (or someone else might mis-hear it) such that it sounds like "gonna".

Comment: In the South East UK at least - "goner" refers to some person or thing that has (or will very soon) ceased to function as Hot Licks said, while "gonna" is the contraction - as in "I'm gonna do something that'll make me a goner"

Comment: In case the answers don't make it clear, "goner" is a totally different word from "gonna". "Gonna" is a phonetic spelling of how many people pronounce "going to", as in, "I'm **gonna** leave and never come back". "Goner" is a person who will soon be gone, as in about to die. "Gonner" could be a phonetic spelling of "gonna" (since some accents add unnecessary 'r's) or it could be a mispelling or archaic spelling of "goner".

Comment: I kind of chuckle whenever I read 'brain fart' because that's what the original layman's term for *cerebral infarction* devolved into... I'm sure someone heard 'brain farc' and thought they heard 'brain *fart*' instead. When I worked in a hospital as a unit coordinator some 20 years ago, the nurses there used to throw around the phrase 'brain farc' with the same meaning as 'brain fart' today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[*Gonner*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/gonner) is a rare spelling variant of *goner*.

**Goner**

> [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goner) *n. slang* One that is ruined or doomed.
>   *"I'm a goner if this plan doesn't work"*
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goner) *n.* someone or something that is going to die or that can no longer be used
>   *"This old computer is a goner. We'll have to get a new one.
>   "*
>
> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goner#Etymology) etymology: gone +‎ -er

Comment: Oh, a spelling mistake! One "n" at least I know I'm not losing my mind :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, it's sometimes pronounced more like "gonna" in the more goombah-infested parts of the US, which may be the source of some of your original confusion. "He's a gohnna!"

Comment: @mxyzplk you mean *my* confusion, NVZ provided the correct answer almost immediately (in just over six minutes). P.S Which parts of the US are "goombah"? Is it the east coast?

Comment: With no disrespect to Josh's fine answer, but I'm accepting yours simply because you were the first to post the correct spelling and explanation.

Answer (score 33):

It is spelled with one 'n' because it comes from "gone" (not from "gonna" - going to) as in earlier expressions like ***[gone goose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gone%20goose) or [gone coon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gone-coon--a).***

***[Goner](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=goner%20)*** (n.):

> - "something dead or about to die, person past recovery, one who is done for in any way," ***1836, American English colloquial, from gone + -er (1)***. From earlier expressions such as gone goose (1830), gone coon, etc. (Etynomline)

- According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20goner%2C%20a%20gonner&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20goner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20gonner%3B%2Cc0) the double ***n*** variant is much less common but probably as old as *goner.*

Comment: Thanks for the etymological info, so the word *goner* is not derived from "going to die" but from *gone*. You live and learn something new every day.

Comment: Coon as in *racoon*, I guess. But nowadays isn't it a highly offensive term?

Comment: Possibly the extra *n* was because of the short *o*? Even though it's already present in gone...

Comment: @Mari-LouA That depends. These days it's highly offensive because it's generally reserved as a racial epitaph targeted at blacks. Historically, it's no different than "you dirty rat".

Comment: I think a more likely root is from "go under". Etymonline says that first appears in 1848, but it was a common among western US mountain men in the 1820's and 30's to say someone had "gone under" as a way of saying they had died. It may have been common slang among general rural populations in the US. It is a small jump from "gone under" to "goner".

Comment: @hatchet - Etymonline cites 1836 as first documented usage. It says that it comes from earlier expressions used to convey the same idea like "gone goose" etc. Gone under may well have been one of those.